# intransitive "park": a vehicle parks somewhere

Tags: verbs

I've noticed the following example sentences from an American dictionary, whereas no British dictionaries list this intransitive usage of "park" with vehicles as subject. I'm wondering if this is really a pondial difference, or if the British dictionaries are just incomplete in their description of British English:

> Cars are only allowed to park on the right side of this street.

> The bus parked behind the museum.

Comment: Dictionary examples are merely examples.  The dictionary examples cannot list all possible usages.  If Bob can intransitively park behind the museum, then the bus can intransitively park behind the museum.  Whether or not busses can park is an entirely different issue.  Voting to close.

Comment: @EllieK The point is those dictionaries fail to record this usage. Good dictionaries list this usage separtely.

Comment: You have little idea about what makes a good dictionary. Coverage is one of the most important criteria. Sadly, only Merriam-Webster notes the crucial usage.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/park_2) a British dictionary that mentions the intransitive form. And [here's](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/park) the Cambridge dictionary entry, which lists both American and British usage, and specifically mentions that they can be either intransitive and transitive. So no, there isn't a "pondial" difference in this respect, and some British dictionaries appear not to suffer from the lack of completeness you describe.

Edit: Sorry, I missed your "with vehicles as subject." Rather than checking dictionaries, I tried searching "cars may park" and "cars can park" in Google's [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams). You can compare occurrences in American English and British English there. It seems that usage is more common in American English, but not by a great deal; it's fair to say that the British use this phrase regularly.

Comment: Well, the intransitive usage in the dictionaries you mentioned actually have people as subject, not vehicle.

Comment: On the other hand, M-W lists intransitive examples where the subject refers to a vehicle.

Comment: @Apollyon I'm sorry, it looks like I missed "with vehicles as subject."